# Flex box items width basing off of parent container width

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a parent container that has a max width and I want there to be 3 boxes to a line. I am using flex for this but I want the boxes to take up the full width of the parent container which I am only able to achieve by hard-coding the width of the boxes.  How can I have them adapt to the width of the sections container rather than me putting a 32% width on the boxes?

**HTML**

```
<div class="account-component>
   <div class="cart-products-container">
      <div class="sections">
            <div class="cart-product">
            </div>
            <div class="cart-product">
            </div>
            <div class="cart-product">
            </div>
            <div class="cart-product">
            </div>
            <div class="cart-product">
            </div>
            <div class="cart-product">
            </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.account-component {
    max-width: 1240px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 100px;
    .sections {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;

        .cart-product {
             width: 32%;
             margin-bottom: 25px;
             height: 445px;
             background-color: pink;
             &:nth-child(3n+2) {
                margin-right: 24px;
                margin-left: 24px;
             }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is the missing closing quotation on your first class also missing in your actual code?

Comment: Also, give `.cart-products-container` the full width of its parent with `flex-grow: 1`.

Answer (score 1):

To get the desired effect, you just need to change:

```
.cart-product {
   flex: 0 0 33%;
   margin-bottom: 25px;
   height: 445px;
   background-color: pink;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can not use percentage on child element if you did not set the `width` (not max-with) of the parent element, because you won't have a width to depend on.

In your case, use `flex` to set the percentage of the child elements.

Here's a sample fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gadawag/0by7dm81/6/

Comment: Not true... you can set a percentage width on flex children without a specified parent width.